# New Leviton GFCI, light flashes red-green-off but will not reset

Tags: electrical

Installed new Leviton GFCI unit but doesn’t have power and will not reset-
Replaced old GFCi unit and placed wires in exact position as old unit, when power came back on led lit up green automatically but it didn’t have power and couldn’t be reset  saw the advice to swap wires top to bottom and vise versa as Leviton GFCIs are normally reserved. Turned power back on and pushed reset, light quickly flashed red then green then off and there is still no power. Any advice on what to do/try next?

Comment: If you have a multimeter, check voltage between hot and neutral wires. Assuming that's ~ 120V, install an ordinary receptacle (temporarily - because presumably this is a place that requires a GFCI) and get that working. Then work step by step *following directions for the specific model of GFCI*. Which screw location is which for hot/neutral and line/load will vary by model. Then follow directions for how to intialize/reset - some have different procedures after a power failure. **Model #???**

Answer (score 2):

HAHAHA - Leviton laughing at us all.

Leviton is a joke for doing this.   Just installed a bunch (30+) of these the past month.

If you turn the power on and your Leviton is GREEN that is bad.   That means it is mis-wired.   I will repeat again green is bad in Leviton world (I have no beef with Leviton and love their products except this issue with the new GFCIs - they are all like this so don't need a model number).

So what do you want?

You want the light to be RED.   I kid you not.    You will have wired it properly when you turn power on and the device is red.   It will then allow you to reset it and it will turn GREEN.

And to answer your question in simple terms when you wire a Leviton GFCI that has four wires you need to flip the blacks (bottom on top and top on bottom) and do the same for the whites.

Comment: Yeah, "red = go" is definitely not great UX :P

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - the first one I did was a second floor bathroom.     I f^&$*$*ing went up and down the stairs 20 times thinking I had a short from something else I was doing that day... turning the breaker off and on and checking.    I actually had the red light on the second try but didn't realize  that it was working so I kept trying to "fix" it.   I even put in the old gfci to see if I was high...    1000 calories later my doctor commends Leviton for my improved cardio.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - is it also good UX to have the exact opposite wiring of every other GFCI made since the invention on electricity?    The two together for all of their current models has to be some joke by the dev department.    This is a rather new issue... ~3 years go or so their GFCIs were not like this.